# Javascript changing an image within a div after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making a web page with an image inside of a div tag. I wrote a script to change the image after a certain amount of time, and it works fine when I test the script alone, however; when I attempt to place the script within my web page, it does not change the image.

Here is the code for my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            images = new Array;
            images[0] = "img2.gif";
            images[1] = "img3.gif";
            images[2] = "img4.gif";
            images[3] = "img5.gif";
            images[4] = "img6.gif";
            images[5] = "img7.gif";
            images[6] = "img8.gif";
            images[7] = "img9.gif";
            images[8] = "img10.gif";

            setInterval( function() {
                changeImage()
            }, 5000);

            x = 0;

            function changeImage() {
                document.getElementById('ad').src = images[x];

                if ( x < 8 ) {
                    x += 1;
                } else if ( x = 9 ) {
                    x = 0;
                }
            }
        </script>

        <img id='ad' src="img.gif">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested this script with the image inside of a div tag and it still works fine. When I put the same code into my web page, it does not work. Also note, the image file names are just examples. The images I am using are from photobucket, so I have very little control over what they are called. Any help I could get on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your console, it's probably throwing an error

Comment: test for equality if(x === 9)

Comment: I edited the formatting of your code (without correcting mistakes) for better readability, next time try to use indentation a little bit more! ;)

Comment: @sferret The other if should be `if( x < 9 )` too

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code inside `window.onload = function() {}`

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "img2.gif";
images[1] = "img3.gif";
images[2] = "img4.gif";
images[3] = "img5.gif";
images[4] = "img6.gif";
images[5] = "img7.gif";
images[6] = "img8.gif";
images[7] = "img9.gif";
images[8] = "img10.gif";

function changeImage() {
  document.getElementById('ad').src = images[x];
  if (x<8) {
    x+=1;
  }

  else if (x===9) {
    x=0;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var x = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    changeImage()
  },5000);
}
```

## Edit

This code has been tested on my local machine and works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var images = new Array();
      for (var i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
        images.push("img" + i + ".gif");
      }
      var x = 0;

      function changeImage() {
        document.getElementById('ad').src = images[x];
        document.getElementById('imgsrc').innerHTML = "<h1>" + images[x] + "</h1>";
        if (x < 8) {
          x += 1;
        } else {
          x = 0;
        }
      }
      window.onload = function() {
        setInterval(function () {
          changeImage();
        }, 1000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="ad" src="img.gif" />
    <div id="imgsrc"><h1>img.gif</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwsjE/3/) is a fiddle of the final code working. JSFiddle doesn't like `window.onload` for some reason, so I had to exclude it. This doesn't really demonstrate my point, but I thought I'd just include it anyway.

Comment: I also cleaned up your code just a bit. Make sure you declare your variables with `var` before you begin using them.

Comment: That should be `else if (x == 9) {`

Comment: Actually it should be x === 9, but who cares... +1

Comment: @SethMcClaine Yes, it could be ===, but == is at least one step closer than = :)

Comment: I would prefer the if to be replaced with `x = (x + 1) % images.length` personally.

Comment: In another note, it should be `if(x < 9)`, this code gets stuck at x=8

Comment: Okay, thank you. I tested this code, however; and found that it did not cycle through the images as before. I placed it within the script tags as with before. Though I personally believe you are correct in that my issue has something to do with the onload event.

Comment: @TrevorFisher Have a look at my edit. I've tested it and it absolutely works.

Comment: Thank you Willem, I appreciate the help, but incrementing the variable "i" will not work in my case, as I have no real control over what photobucket calls the image file. That is why I used an array, as it seemed like a way around this. Perhaps it is where I am trying to place the script within the web page, or perhaps I am, for some reason, unable to access the img from within the div.

Comment: @TrevorFisher Well I was just doing the loop to remove that ugly block of code. The point is this code should iterate through an array of strings, replacing the src of an `img` element with a new string every few seconds. Which seems like exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works to change the image `src` in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snB2a/1/

Comment: you don't need `$(document).ready()` or `window.onload` for jsfiddle

Comment: And by putting what there is in the fiddle, we know that that must be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your variables images and x to longer names. What can happen is, if some other code in your page, or worse, some code in one of the script file you page references, use variable "x" without declare it locally, then it would actually modify your "x" variable.

Here is an example to demonstrate the problem:

```
function something()
{
  for (x = 0; i < 10; x++)
    dosomethingelse();
}
```

If the above function is called in your page, then it will overwrite your "x" variable. The following code is safe:

```
function something()
{
  var x;
  for (x = 0; i < 10; x++)
    dosomethingelse();
}
```

Comment: A fair point, but not the actual cause of the issue in this instance.